# Microsoft SQL: CASE WHEN vs ISNULL/NULLIF

Tags: sql-server, null

Besides readability is there any significant benifit to using a CASE WHEN statement vs ISNULL/NULLIF when guarding against a divide by 0 error in SQL?

```
CASE WHEN (BeginningQuantity + BAdjustedQuantity)=0 THEN 0 
ELSE EndingQuantity/(BeginningQuantity + BAdjustedQuantity) END
```

vs

```
ISNULL((EndingQuantity)/NULLIF(BeginningQuantity + BAdjustedQuantity,0),0)
```

Comment: To answer the titled question:  NULLIF is implemented as a CASE WHEN so it's possible to formulate a CASE WHEN that performs identically in both timing and results.  ISNULL however is an intrinsic function.  Given ISNULL(<exp1>,<exp2>), <exp1> is not evaluated twice when not null - a feat one can't duplicate using CASE WHEN.  Moreover the data type returned from ISNULL can be different from a CASE WHEN implementation.  Since COALESCE is implemented using CASE WHEN its results will match a CASE WHEN implementation rather than a (possibly nested) ISNULL simulation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that NULL is different from 0.  So the two code snippets in the question can return different results for the same input.

For example, if BeginningQuantity is NULL, the first expression evaluates to NULL:

```
CASE WHEN (NULL + ?)=0 THEN 0 ELSE ?/(NULL + ?) END
```

Now (NULL + ?) equals NULL, and NULL=0 is false, so the ELSE clause is evaluated, giving ?/(NULL+?), which results in NULL.  However, the second expression becomes:

```
ISNULL((?)/NULLIF(NULL + ?,0),0)
```

Here NULL+? becomes NULL, and because NULL is not equal to 0, the NULLIF returns the first expression, which is NULL. The outer ISNULL catches this and returns 0.

So, make up your mind: are you guarding against divison by zero, or divison by NULL? ;-)

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to protect against division by 0

Comment: The cost of the division will dwarf the cost of any CASE or ISNULL checks, so I'd take the most readable solution.  Another option is a WHERE clause to exclude rows that would divide by zero.

Answer (score 4):

In your example I think the performance is negligible. But in other cases, depending on the complexity of your divisor, the answer is 'it depends'.

[Here is an interesting blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-efficient-handling-of-divide) on the topic:

For readability, I like the Case/When.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using Isnull/Nullif is faster than using Case When. I rather the isnull/nullif.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ISNULL, but try to format it so it shows the meaning better:

```
SELECT
    x.zzz
        ,x.yyyy
        ,ISNULL(
                   EndingQuantity / NULLIF(BeginningQuantity+BAdjustedQuantity,0)
                ,0)
        ,x.aaa
    FROM xxxx...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN (coalesce(BeginningQuantity,0) + coalesce(BAdjustedQuantity,0))=0 THEN 0 ELSE coalesce(EndingQuantity,0)/(coalesce(BeginningQuantity,0) + coalesce(BAdjustedQuantity,0)) END
```

your best option imho

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the little more simplify upbuilded sql  query.

```
SELECT 

(ISNULL([k1],0) + ISNULL([k2],0)) /

CASE WHEN (
(
   CASE WHEN [k1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN [k2] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) > 0 )
THEN
(
  CASE WHEN [k1] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN [k2] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
ELSE 1 END

FROM dbo.[Table]
```