# How to avoid division by 0 in ms-sql select statement?

Tags: sql-server, select, null, divide-by-zero

I've read about `nullif`, but haven't been able to put together a `SELECT` statement to use it properly:

```
Select (num/total) as percent ...
```

**If total is 0, I want to return Null**. How do I revise the statement?

if I say

```
select (num/nullif(total, 0)) as percent ...
```

what does it mean to divide by Null?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/858492/238688) to a related question may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT [percent] = CASE WHEN total = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (num/total) END 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to the second part of your question:

> what does it mean to divide by Null?

The result of an arithmetic calculation which uses a `NULL` value is `NULL`, or to [put it another way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Arithmetic_operations):

> Because Null is not a data value, but a marker for an unknown value,
>   using mathematical operators on Null results in an unknown value,
>   which is represented by Null.

So the statement

```
select (num/nullif(total, 0)) as percent
```

will return `NULL` if `total = 0`. The use of `CASE`, as presented by Tim, is an equally valid
way of handling the problem.